# Como alterar um nome de uma string

Tags: c, string

Estou fazendo uma questão no uri [Substituição de Tag](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1254), que se tem que substituir um nome por outro porém não estou tendo sucesso, só consigo com nomes normais sem caracteres

Meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char nome[] = "Stack overflow";
  char *ptr;
  char aux[900];
  int cont = 0;
  ptr = strtok(nome, " ");
  while(ptr != NULL)
  {
    if(cont == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(ptr, "overflow") == 0)
        {
            strcpy(aux, "certo");
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(aux, ptr);
            strcat(aux, " ");
        }
        cont++;
    }
    else
    {
        if(strcmp(ptr, "overflow") == 0)
        {
            strcat(aux, "certo");
        }
        else
        {
            strcat(aux, ptr);
            strcat(aux, " ");
        }
    }
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
   puts(aux);
}
```

Comment: Onde está a parte que interpreta `tag` ou não `tag` ? Pessoalmente acho mais fácil iterar os carateres normalmente ao invés de utilizar `strtok`, e gerar um buffer de saída só com os carateres corretos, para depois ser só mostrar

Comment: Como faria para alterar  nome, eu tentei fazer um for passando a frase com o que era para ser alterado porém outras partes do texto foram alteradas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para substituir todas as string contidas em uma string, você pode implementar algo como:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int strrepstr( char * dst, const char * src, const char * oldstr, const char * newstr )
{
    char * p = NULL;
    char * aux = NULL;
    int oldstrlen = 0;
    int count = 0;

    if( !dst || !src || !oldstr || !newstr )
        return -1;

    oldstrlen = strlen( oldstr );

    if( !oldstrlen )
        return -1;

    p = strstr( src, oldstr );
    aux = (char*) src;

    strcpy( dst, "\0" );

    while( p )
    {
        strncat( dst, aux, p - aux );

        strcat( dst, newstr );
        count++;

        p += oldstrlen;
        aux = p;

        p = strstr( aux, oldstr );
    }

    strcat( dst, aux );

    return count;
}

char main( void )
{
    char entrada[] = "O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!";
    char saida[100];

    strrepstr( saida, entrada, "Roma", "Paris" );

    printf("Entrada: %s\n", entrada );
    printf("Saida: %s\n", saida );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Entrada: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!
Saida: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Paris!
```